# Radio button checked issue

Tags: php, html, radio-button

My question was about the browser matter as far as I see. 
I asked is there any solution to tell browser to move checked="checked" between radio buttons. I thought there will be a quick solution for this but this case is just confusing. I changed my code now. I use select list element now.

I have a form, and I get the actual settings with php, but the matter is this:

When the radio button 1 comes `checked="checked"` if that is actual, after it when I change to other option in post I get `checked="checked"`'s value, I was wondering is there a solution for this or Javascript is needed something like onclick"this.checked otherone uncheck" ?

```
if($type==1) { $like = 'checked="checked"'; } else { $ref='checked="checked"'; }

<form method="post" action="process.php" id="fbform" name="fbform">
<div class="radio">
<p>Like button: </p>
<input type="radio" name="tipi" <?=$like?> value="1" />
</div>
<div class="radio1">
<p>Link:</p> 
<input type="radio" name="tipi" <?=$ref?> value="2" />
</div>
</form>
```

Process.php file code

```
<?php
$mysql->update('settings'," tipi='".$_POST['tipi]."' ");
?>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Show some code, that might explain your problem much better. I suspect it has to do with the radio buttons having the same name, but I can't be sure without looking at your code.

Comment: Please show us your html code.

Comment: Ofcourse radio buttons must have the same name otherway that posts 2 POST variables.

Comment: Show your codes you're confusing us.

Comment: There is nothing to be confused man.
Here I just added some more code.

Comment: Ghostology, you use the word "actual" in your question and "when I change to other option in post". Can you clarify what you mean? What is "actual" if you change something? When do you send the request?

Comment: @Ghostology there's a little logical incongruence in the cause/effect flow. You want a user to have it selected according to the value he sent when he will select it? :/

Comment: The process.php is called _after_ the submission

Comment: First when page is loaded it begins like this:

FORM
RADIO BUTTON (IF THIS IS CHECKED WILL HAVE THE MARK)
RADIO BUTTON (IF THIS IS CHECKED WILL HAVE THE MARK)
SUBMIT BUTTON,

AFTER USER CHOOSES ONE WHICH DOESN'T HAVE THE MARK, AND WE MUST SEND THEN THE SELECTED ONE

Comment: DON'T USE UPPERCASE. Second, how is the browser supposed to know which one mark as selected if you don't tell him? how do you tell him which it is, based on what?

Comment: checked="checked" tags, but forget it I used some javascript and just changed this thing at all. Maybe someday someone posts a solution.

Comment: I doubt it, since even you can't tell which is the problem. You might also want to share the answer, so we (and whoever passes here) can see what you did and (hopefully) meant

Comment: My question was about the browser matter as far as I see. I asked is there any solution to tell browser to move checked="checked" between radio buttons. I thought there will be a quick solution for this but this case is just confusing. I changed my code now. I use select list element now.

Answer (score 0):

checked is a marker tag - it does not care  , as long if the word 'checked' is there.

Comment: Man I want to tell user the actual checked option, so Browser gets the checked one as selected. Browsers do care for checked tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can do better with this. Also, IDs are used only for CSS or JS, and moreover must be UNIQUE.

```
<div class="radio">
<p>Like button: </p>

<input type="radio" name="tipi" id="tipi" <?php echo ($type == '1')?'checked="checked"' : '';?> value="1" />

</div>

<div class="radio1">

<p>Link:</p> 
<input type="radio" name="tipi" id="tipi2" <?php echo ($type=='2')?'checked="checked"' : '';?> value="2" />

</div>
```

Then you access them in php

```
$tipi = $_POST['tipi']; //either 1 or 2
```

Comment: You maybe misunderstood me, I am posting these values with a <form> and I need same $_POST['tipi'] with different value, the value that comes to post part is the checked ones value.

Comment: It's according to $type, you get that value from wherever you want

Comment: @Ghostology: *"the value that comes to post part is the checked ones value"* - this is how it is, by definition. HTTP doesn't change only because you want it to. But if you describe your problem better, folks might be able to give you some actual tips anyway.

Comment: Man I just asked is there a trigger in browsers to change the checked radio boxes :S. This is all.

Comment: @Ghostology nothing is clear of what you asked, otherwise someone would have given the right answer

Comment: @Ghostology calm down a bit. People are trying to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do:

```
<div class="radio">
  <p>Like button: </p>
  <input type="radio" name="tipi" id="tipi1" value="1"<?php if ($type == 1) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?> />
</div>
<div class="radio1">
  <p>Link:</p> 
  <input type="radio" name="tipi" id="tipi2" value="2"<?php if ($type != 1) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?> />
</div>
```

I have changed the id's because you had two elements with the same id, which will never work, even if those elements are part of the same group.

Answer (score 0):

you need very simple changes in your code..See below code:

first of all you need to define variables at very top of the page/Code:

```
$like = ""; 
$ref = "";
```

Now your code will working good as per my knowledge..

Thanks.

Comment: $like, $ref are NULL because every after change the page is reloaded and when they go through if condition just one of them get the value.

Comment: not actually..sometimes it have some garbage values stored. so you need to define variables NULL as it good coding practice too...Thanks.

Comment: @Chandresh what garbage values are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Ghostology: Not sure about your query ... But all I can do is explain you the working of the radio button.

suppose there are two radio buttons inside a form:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioTest" value="1" checked />
<input type="radio" name="radioTest" value="0"  />
```

Here checked specifies the button which will be checked(or turned on) during page load.

Now suppose we check the second button and submit this form, now we get the value 0 against the parameter 'radioTest' as radio button with value 0 is checked.

Now when page loads again with some value of radio buttons. You would want the proper radio button to be checked. 
For this case I guess u can use if/else condition like:
    <% if(radioTest.value == 1){     %>
     
     
    <% }else{                        %>
     
     
    <% }                             %>